# Problem with real-time clock since upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, realtime

**SEE UPDATES BELOW**

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10 using the software update process. The update completed without any errors, and Ubuntu 17.10 is now running without any major issues.

However, I was running a script previously that uses `rtcwake` which has since stopped working. The script automatically hibernates my laptop after a set period of time in sleep mode, and was working perfectly in Ubuntu 17.04.

In the process of troubleshooting, I discovered that the problem was with `rtcwake` which is complaining about `/dev/rtc0` missing.

Here is output from a sample `rtcwake` command:

```
peter@haven:~$ rtcwake -m no -s 1300
rtcwake: assuming RTC uses UTC ...
rtcwake: /dev/rtc0: unable to find device: No such file or directory
```

I verified that in fact, that directory is missing. Since this was working prior to the upgrade, I have to assume that it was there previously, but I don't know for sure.

In researching the error, I found some suggestions to get further information with `timedatectl` and `hwclock`, so here are the results from those commands as well.

Output of `timedatectl`:

```
peter@haven:~$ timedatectl
      Local time: Fri 2017-10-27 19:06:26 EDT
  Universal time: Fri 2017-10-27 23:06:26 UTC
        RTC time: n/a
       Time zone: America/New_York (EDT, -0400)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Output of `hwclock --debug`:

```
peter@haven:~$ sudo hwclock --debug
[sudo] password for peter: 
hwclock from util-linux 2.30.1
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Trying to open: /dev/rtc
Trying to open: /dev/misc/rtc
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

Has anyone else experienced any similar issues since upgrading? If not, please offer any suggestions how best to proceed with my troubleshooting.

**UPDATE**

When I boot with my old kernel, `4.10.0-37-generic` the real-time clock works fine.

I get the following RTC messages in `dmesg` when I boot the `4.13.0-16-generic` kernel:

```
peter@haven:~$ dmesg | grep -i rtc
[    0.089393] RTC time: 17:03:55, date: 11/01/17
[    1.238784] rtc_cmos 00:01: RTC can wake from S4
[    1.238794] rtc_cmos: probe of 00:01 failed with error -16
[    1.295459] hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
```

**UPDATE #2**

Well, I was starting to believe that I had a hardware issue, since discovering I was unable to save changes to my BIOS and could not boot from USB.  As it turns out, my laptop was bitten by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147 causing my BIOS to be locked in a read-only state.

Once I resolved the BIOS issue, and fixed the USB boot problem, I did a live boot of Ubuntu 17.10.  The issue with my real time clock still exists under this clean boot scenario, yet when I boot other distros, like Linux Mint 18.3 and the real time clock works fine.  I feel this definitely has something to do with the Ubuntu install, perhaps even a kernel bug.

**UPDATE #3**

More evidence to suggest this is a kernel bug: I live-booted a copy of Antergos Linux, which was using the Arch kernel `4.14.12-1-ARCH` and it exhibited the same problem with the real time clock as Ubuntu 17.10.  In addition, I confirmed that the Linux Mint version I booted earlier (see Update #2) was on the Ubuntu kernel `4.10.0-38-generic`.

So, I suspect that sometime between kernels 4.10 and 4.13 this bug was introduced.  Can anyone provide me with information for filing a kernel bug?

**UPDATE Jan. 30, 2018**

Kernel bug reported on Launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1743027) and with upstream kernel developers.

Comment: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/hwclock-4175428705/ led me to http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/149704-dev-rtc-doesnt-exist.html which says to run `make menuconfig`, but this is from a while ago and another flavor, so I'm not sure how relevant it is.  EDIT also this https://serverfault.com/a/852008

Comment: @brndn2k, I did follow the suggestions in the links you provided, but they did not work for me.  Although I did not run `make menuconfig` I validated that the relevant options for RTC were enabled in my existing kernel config.

Comment: I am also affected by this on Linux 4.14.14 self compiled on Slackware 14.2. My system is a laptop Fujitsu A555 (`$ inxi -v 1
System:    Host: slackware Kernel: 4.14.14 x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Xfce 4.12.4 Distro: Slackware 14.2
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-5005U (-MT-MCP-) speed/max: 1423/1900 MHz
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (53.1% used)
Info:      Processes: 172 Uptime: 5 days Memory: 5276.0/11917.1MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.53`).

@pbmilley it might be useful to post your system specs and a link to your launchpad bug report.

Comment: @AadityaBagga, thanks for confirming the issue.  I've taken your suggestion and added the link to my Launchpad bug report in the description.  And here is my system info:

Comment: `System:    Host: haven Kernel: 4.13.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Gnome 3.26.2 Distro: Ubuntu 17.10
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-4510U (-HT-MCP-) speed/max: 2593/3100 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
           Display Server: wayland (X.Org 1.19.5 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.05hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile
           version: 4.5 Mesa 17.2.4`

Comment: `Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (12.4% used)
Info:      Processes: 257 Uptime: 4:11 Memory: 2480.4/15932.8MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.37`

Answer (score 0):

This has been confirmed as a bug in the Linux kernel (follow the status of the bug here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199033).

A workaround is to custom configure the kernel, using `make menuconfig`, and disable support for the `CONFIG_WDAT_WDT` driver. This removes the conflict with the RTC driver and allows it to run normally.

Comment: Guide for configuring your own kernel on Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel